# Calculate streak on multiple columns in pandas without apply

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame like this one (column "row" can be ignored, it's there only to be able to reference it later):

```
  row  |   date     |  type1  |  type2  | column1 | column2  
------------------------------------------------------------
   1   | 2019-01-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    0
   2   | 2019-01-01 |  123    |    B    |    1    |    1
   3   | 2019-02-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    1
   4   | 2019-03-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    0
   5   | 2019-04-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    1
   6   | 2019-04-01 |  123    |    B    |    0    |    1
   7   | 2019-05-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    0
   8   | 2019-05-01 |  123    |    B    |    1    |    1
   9   | 2019-06-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    1
  10   | 2019-07-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    0
  11   | 2019-08-01 |  123    |    A    |    0    |    0
  12   | 2019-08-01 |  123    |    B    |    1    |    1
  13   | 2019-09-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    1
  14   | 2019-10-01 |  123    |    A    |    0    |    1
  15   | 2019-10-01 |  123    |    B    |    1    |    0
  16   | 2019-11-01 |  123    |    A    |    1    |    0
  17   | 2019-01-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    1
  18   | 2019-01-01 |  456    |    B    |    1    |    1
  19   | 2019-02-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    1
  20   | 2019-03-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    0
  21   | 2019-04-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    1
  22   | 2019-04-01 |  456    |    B    |    0    |    1
  23   | 2019-05-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    0
  24   | 2019-05-01 |  456    |    B    |    1    |    1
  25   | 2019-06-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    1
  26   | 2019-07-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    0
  27   | 2019-08-01 |  456    |    A    |    0    |    0
  28   | 2019-08-01 |  456    |    B    |    1    |    1
  29   | 2019-09-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    1
  30   | 2019-10-01 |  456    |    A    |    0    |    1
  31   | 2019-10-01 |  456    |    B    |    1    |    0
  32   | 2019-11-01 |  456    |    A    |    1    |    0
```

I want a new column that gives, grouped per "type1", the streak of (column1 for past dates) and (column2 for the current row). The part that says "for past dates" is the key here.

For instance, row 6 contains the streak for column1 for all dates before '2019-04-01' (rows 1 to 4 inclusively) as well as column2 for row 6.

The result is this:

```
   row  |   date     |  type1 |  type2  | column1 | column2 |  streak
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    | 2019-01-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   2    | 2019-01-01 |  123   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    1
   3    | 2019-02-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    3
   4    | 2019-03-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   5    | 2019-04-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    5
   6    | 2019-04-01 |  123   |    B    |    0    |    1    |    5
   7    | 2019-05-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   8    | 2019-05-01 |  123   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    1
   9    | 2019-06-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    3
   10   | 2019-07-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   11   | 2019-08-01 |  123   |    A    |    0    |    0    |    0
   12   | 2019-08-01 |  123   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    5
   13   | 2019-09-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    2
   14   | 2019-10-01 |  123   |    A    |    0    |    1    |    3
   15   | 2019-10-01 |  123   |    B    |    1    |    0    |    0
   16   | 2019-11-01 |  123   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   17   | 2019-01-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    1
   18   | 2019-01-01 |  456   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    1
   19   | 2019-02-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    3
   20   | 2019-03-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   21   | 2019-04-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    5
   22   | 2019-04-01 |  456   |    B    |    0    |    1    |    5
   23   | 2019-05-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   24   | 2019-05-01 |  456   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    1
   25   | 2019-06-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    3
   26   | 2019-07-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
   27   | 2019-08-01 |  456   |    A    |    0    |    0    |    0
   28   | 2019-08-01 |  456   |    B    |    1    |    1    |    5
   29   | 2019-09-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    1    |    2
   30   | 2019-10-01 |  456   |    A    |    0    |    1    |    3
   31   | 2019-10-01 |  456   |    B    |    1    |    0    |    0
   32   | 2019-11-01 |  456   |    A    |    1    |    0    |    0
```

Also note that row 17 doesn't have a streak value of 3, because column type1 contains a different value, so the streak starts again.

Since the DataFrame contains around 100M rows, I want to avoid using an "apply", since that would be very slow.

Is there a better, faster way to do it?

Comment: Hi, shouldn't row 2 have streak value 2?

Comment: No, because both first rows have date 2019-01-01. So it should take the streak of rows before 2019-01-01 (there is none, so 0) + column2 of row 2 = 1. Basically, it should ignore row1 entirely